# Prevent unnecessary ad loads when ViewPager is swiped back to previously seen page

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager backed by a FragmentPagerAdapter. Each page is a ListFragment. I need to show an ad in each page. Currently the ad is loaded in the ListAdapter.getView. This results in unnecessary ad loads when the pages are swiped in quick succession or when swiping back to previously viewed pages (since they have been destroyed and need to be recreated). I need the ad to be part of the list view so they can be scrolled away, instead of taking up a fixed space on the screen.

I tried keeping an array of ads in the parent activity and reuse these across the fragments. It seems to work, but with random strange behavior. Partial ad going behind the first list item, partial ad getting truncated and not visible, etc. Scrolling the list up and down fixes these layout problems.

Is this the right way to do it? What are the other alternatives? I basically want to ensure minimum ad loads from a bandwidth perspective. Many of my users will be on 2G networks.

I know how to put the ad outside of the list view and keep it fixed so only one ad is loaded. But I'd like to go for the scrollable ad because it frees up valuable screen space.

[image: what i want it to look like]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the ad as list [headerview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29), it will be inflated only once and will be scrollable. Also consider to change pager.setOffscreenPageLimit() it will manage the number of pages that stay in memory(for the view pager) and will prevent recreation of the fragments.

Comment: I've already tried the headerview; same layout problems. Increasing offScreenPageLimit is a possibility but how do I decide how much is acceptable? What metrics should I look out for? I have about 6-7 tabs and sub 50 items in each list.